# Show fb Group Wall on Website - where to start?

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to show a group wall on my website - recent posts and pics of those who have liked the group.

I have created an app although I am not too sure why - isn't an app something which runs inside fb, when I want this to connect to fb externally?

Anyway, where do I start? Can anyone give me a list of steps to get a solution like this under way? I am going round in circles reading the fb documention on the developer site. I write in c# in ASP.Net. Are there any tutorials? An SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use an rss feed of http://groupfeed.climatesceptics.org ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google reveals: [facebook c# sdk](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk).  Does that help?

This could also be of use: [Facebook for websites](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/).

For future reference, please do some research before asking a question so you don't get down-voted ;)

Comment: The first link does - the second not (I did say in my post that was the case) - I trawled through the fb developer site getting nowhere - it confused rather than helped. I have no idea what down-voting is nor do I care...